# How to make a scrollable dropdown menu in bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I've seen some great code examples for dropdown menus you can scroll through but sadly most don't work with bootstrap 5. Is there any modern way to do this?

Comment: Please post the code you've attempted. Nothing effecting the scrolling of a dropdown has changed in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean a fixed height for the menu?

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Click on Me
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below css for scrollable dropdown. Here You can set `max-height: 100vh` which limits it to 100% of the viewport's height. So, It will show in any viewport nicely.

Don't forget to minus header height from `calc(100vh - 150px)`. 150px is the height of the header on my site example. You can replace as per your site. which is above the height of the dropdown.

```
.dropdown-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}
```